# xml-файлы еще используется в разработке новых приложениях на спринге или только аннтоации?

Tags: java, spring

Стоит ли тратиь время на изучение использование xml-файлов в спринге?

Comment: есть не только xml и аннотации...xml, аннотации, java, groovy конфигурации...и возможно еще что-то забыл. Плюс можно и кастомные конфигурации запилить. Старые приложения как ни странно до сих пор используют xml конфигурации. И таких приложений несколько больше чем Вы бы могли подумать. Плюс XML-конфигурации имеют некоторые плюсы относительно конфигураций в аннотациях.

Comment: и что значит "изучение использование xml-файлов в спринге"?.. Вы так говорите, как будто это отдельный фреймворк какой-то который нужно освоить. Вы либо умеете конфигурировать Спринг, либо нет. А уж где и как  - это третье дело. И если использование xml-конфигураций у Вас вызывают сложности то скорее всего вы не понимаете и осознаёте как на самом деле работать со Спрингом.

Comment: В изучении xml-конфигураций есть один плюс: Вы сможете понять как работает Спринг.

Comment: В новых приложениях, по усмотрению автора проекта тоже могут быть использованы xml-конфигурации. Вы должны понимать, что не все способы конфигурирования равнозначные. У них могут быть свои плюсы и минусы. У них могут быть разные возможности. И в разных ситуациях разные способы могут подходить лучше или хуже. Groovy config на данный момент наверное самый гибкий...

Comment: В случае аннотаций и Java-конфигов вам придётся перекомпилировать приложение для правки конфигурации. В случае xml и Groovy конфигов, Вы сможете изменить конфигурацию без перекомпиляции и перезагрузить контекст. Это может быть полезно. Особенно когда Вам звонят в 12 ночи и доступа к исходникам у под рукой нет. При этом в xml и Groovy конфигурацию можно и с телефона правку внести, подключившись по ssh к серверу.

Comment: @МихаилРебров что бы не перекомпиливать конфиг на джаве, нужно выносить в файл то что может меняться. Понятное дело что забить жестко в коде данные это такое себе. Посему такое себе преимущество ибо оно зависит от правильности написания того самого конфига. А про XML: он имеет свойство раздуваться до такой степени что его попросту становится невозможно читать и поддерживать. А Java конфиг поддерживать легче, при чем в разы. Везде есть + и -. Сейчас все стараются пересесть на Java конфиг (насколько я знаю), но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @Tsyklop, Я и не говорю о наличии какого бы то ни было ультимативного решения. Я как раз таки написал ровным счетом то же, что Вы повторили. У всего есть свои плюсы и минусы и для каждого конкретного случая лучше решать, основываясь на реалиях проекта. Я в свою очередь не останавливался сильно на Джава конфиге, потому что все теми же преимуществами и даже больше обладает Groovy конфиг. Мне самому приходится на разных проектах использовать все типы конфигурации и их гибридами и в classpath при необходимости прокидывать для пущей гибкости.

Comment: @Tsyklop, Только речь не о нас с Вами. Я остановился на плюсах xml-конфигураций, только потому что, что в контексте данного вопроса ТС видел только аннотации и xml и для него выглядело все очень ясно. Я просто хотел показать  что не всегда всё так однозначно. Аннотации и SpringBoot, это всё здорово, я тоже ими пользуюсь. Но разработчики, которые с них начинают думают что Спринг это MVC фреймворк и они не понимают как он работает. Я против обучения в стиле поставьте такую-то аннотацию над тем то классом и будет Вам счастье... а что зачем и почему никто никому не объясняет.

Comment: @Tsyklop, а мысль которую я пытался донести: это то, что когда ты по-настоящему понимаешь как работает Спринг, тебе не нужно каким-то особым образом сидеть и  долго осваивать новые виды конфигураций. И обратное: если xml-конфигурация вызывает ступор и Вы не знаете что с этим делать, то скорее всего Вы что-то пропустили на моменте освоения Спринга. Я не пытаюсь топить за повсеместное использование xml-конфигурирования. Я говорю о том, что попытка изучения данного вида конфигурации может быть полезна в плане получения какой-либо теоритической информации о том как спринг устроен.

Comment: В любом случае каждый всегда выбирает сам, основываясь на требованиях и своих предпочтениях и тут нету никакого уникального рецепта. Но перед тем как выбрать бывает полезно попробовать каждый вариант, чтобы  как минимум иметь представление.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно да. Тем более что там нет ничего особо сложного. XML дает возможность, например, подменять реализацию бинов не запуская перекомпиляцию исходников, подсовывать свои BeanPostProcessor-ы и кучу всего, причем довольно просто. А если вы будете работать не в стартапе, а в ентерпрайзе, то без этого никак. Там вероятность встретить XML почти 100%, так как проекты созданы давно. А к новым приложениям могут быть те же требования как и к старым - чтобы инструкции не переписывать, чтобы людей не переучивать и т.д. Кроме того, есть риски привязки классов к конкретному фреймворку - спрингу из-за аннотаций например. Для кого-то такие риски не совсем приемлимы.